# Generate random number dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to generate a random number per day using dart, i know how to generate a random number using Random function but no idea how to execute this only once time per day.
Thanks you everyone.

Comment: missing the most important information: where do you want to do that? 
What do you have already tried?
What do you want to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information I'd say- save this random number either in local database or better yet- SharedPreferences functionality, with date stamp. Then when code starts it'll check stored number and date it was created. Then its a simple matter of `date.isNotToday ? generateNumber() : null;`